# How do I redirect to a not-authorized page instead of the login page when the user is already logged in?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

How do I set my Authorize(Roles="blah") token to redirect to a "You're not authorized to do this" when a user is already logged in but isn't in the correct role?  Currently it redirects to the login page which isn't what we're after.  We feel that it's confusing for the user to be redirected to this page as they're already logged in.  In the event however they're not logged in, it should redirect to the login page.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The way [AuthorizeAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute.aspx) is designed is that it will first look if the user is authenticated and then look if he is in role. If any of these conditions aren't satisfied it will simply return return a [HttpUnauthorizedResult](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.httpunauthorizedresult.aspx) which in turn will set the response code to 401. To achieve what you want you will need to implement your own [IAuthorizationFiler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.iauthorizationfilter.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Your login page can check to see if the user is authenticated (HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated), then redirect to a different page.

Or alternatively, render differently for an authenticated user (hide the login form and instead display an appropriate message).

Comment: Seems like there's a lot of redirecting going on here.  First the controller attribute (Authorize) checks to see if the user is logged in and if they are then it passes to the role provider to see if the user is authorized or passes the user back to the login page.  If the login page detects that the user is logged in then it re-redirects them to a not authorized page, this seems like a kludge.  I think I would prefer this handled in the IAuthorizationFilter so that there's not so much redirecting.  It seems cleaner and easier to read.

Comment: "I think I would prefer this handled in the IAuthorizationFilter" - each to his own, but I think redirecting is the simpler solution.  As noted, you can avoid the second redirect by having the login page render differently for logged in users.

Answer (score 1):

You should check out Kazi Manzur Rashid's blog post on custom authorization providers: http://weblogs.asp.net/rashid/archive/2009/09/06/asp-net-mvc-and-authorization-and-monkey-patching.aspx.  It can be a pretty complex beast to do it properly.  So it comes down to a few options, 2 rather simple ways of doing it "wrong" and one rather complex way of doing it "right".  Your call.  Either way - it's worth reading the blog post.